# Referencing string with pointers

Tags: c++, string, literals, access-violation, const-cast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does simple C code receive segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-does-simple-c-code-receive-segmentation-fault)

Why code snippet 2 doesn't behave like snippet 1?

```
//Code snippet 1
char pstr[] = "helloworld";
char *p = pstr; 
p[2] = 'd';

//Code snippet 2
char *p = "helloworld";
p[2] = 'd'; //error: access violation
```

P.S Forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"helloworld"` is an array of `const char`.  There's a hole in the type system which allows you to point to it with a `char*`, because a lot of code exists which uses a `char *` to point to readonly data and this is safe.

But `const_cast` rules apply, you can't actually write to the `const` data even if you make a non-const pointer to it.

Answer (score 3):

The first snippet creates an array of char and initializes its contents to "helloworld". Then you change its third element.

The second one simply creates a pointer to char that points to a *string literal*. Then you attempt to change the third character of that literal. String literals are not writable in code produced by many modern compilers.

EDIT:

GCC used to have an `-fwritable-strings` option that enabled string literals to be writable, since there is legacy code around that depends on this behaviour. That option was removed in the [GCC 4.0 release series](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.0/changes.html).

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could tell us in what way they're behaving differently.

But as a guess, I think your problem is that the second form has 'p' pointing to a string in read-only memory.  Attempts to write through the pointer 'p' would result in a program failure.

I can tell you that the Gnu c++ compiler will warn you about this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing when you say "doesn't behave like" you mean one throws an illegal access exception (or something similar) while the other gives a compile time warning or error?

The answer is that in the first case, you're creating a pointer to your own memory, and copying the c9ontents into it.  At that point the compiler forgets it used to be a pointer to static memory; the run time system, however, doesn't forget.

In the other case, the compiler "knows" p is a pointer to static memory, and so has the chance to say "whoa, dude, can't do that".

But this is a *bit* of a guess without knowing exactly what it does differently.  it's also going to be compiler and implementation dependent.

Comment: Snippet 1 is perfectly legal, he operates on the copied string.  There is no "pointer to static memory", the pointer is to the array `pstr` which is writable.